# MySQL - Many-To-Many Relationship between three entities

Tags: mysql, database-design, spring-data-jpa, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I am having trouble figuring out the best design for my many-to-many relationship in my database. My project allows users to create what we are calling log alarms. A log alarm will check if a given log meets certain criteria and, if so, it will send a message to an AWS SNS topic. What I want to do is relate log alarms to AWS SNS topics. I also want to relate which user assigned that log alarm to that AWS SNS topic.

I have a table class XRefUserLogAlarmSNSTopic. It has three foreign keys. The goal of this table is to relate which SNS topics are related to what log alarms and to indicate which user made the relation. This seems rather messy to me and I get all sorts of errors when I try to create new log alarms or join tables in Spring JPA. My question is, is there are better database structure for what I am trying to achieve

````
    UserId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Password TEXT NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Dashboard LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (UserId),
    UNIQUE (Username),
    UNIQUE (Email)
);

CREATE TABLE SNSTopics (
    SNSTopicId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TopicName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    TopicArn VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SNSTopicId),
    UNIQUE (TopicName),
    UNIQUE (TopicArn)
);

CREATE TABLE LogGroups (
    LogGroupId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (LogGroupId),
    UNIQUE (Name)
);

CREATE TABLE Keywords (
    KeywordId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Word VARCHAR(70),
    PRIMARY KEY (KeywordId),
    UNIQUE (Word)
);

CREATE TABLE LogAlarms (
    LogAlarmId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LogLevel VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL CHECK (LogLevel IN ('TRACE', 'DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARN', 'ERROR')),
    Comparison VARCHAR(2) CHECK (Comparison IN ('==', '<', '<=', '>', '>=')),
    AlarmName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    KeywordRelationship CHAR(3) CHECK (KeywordRelationship IN ('ANY', 'ALL', NULL)),
    PRIMARY KEY (LogAlarmId),
    UNIQUE (AlarmName)
);

CREATE TABLE MetricAlarms (
    MetricAlarmId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    AlarmArn VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (MetricAlarmId),
    UNIQUE (AlarmArn)
);

CREATE TABLE XRefUserMetricAlarm (
    UserMetricAlarmId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    UserId INT NOT NULL,
    MetricAlarmId INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (UserMetricAlarmId),
    FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES Users(UserId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (MetricAlarmId) REFERENCES MetricAlarms(MetricAlarmId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE (UserId, MetricAlarmId)
);

CREATE TABLE XRefLogAlarmLogGroup (
    LogAlarmLogGroupId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LogAlarmId INT NOT NULL,
    LogGroupId INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (LogAlarmLogGroupId),
    FOREIGN KEY (LogAlarmId) REFERENCES LogAlarms(LogAlarmId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (LogGroupId) REFERENCES LogGroups(LogGroupId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE (LogAlarmId, LogGroupId)
);

CREATE TABLE XRefLogAlarmKeyword (
    LogAlarmKeywordId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LogAlarmId INT NOT NULL,
    KeywordId INT NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (LogAlarmKeywordId),
    FOREIGN KEY (LogAlarmId) REFERENCES LogAlarms(LogAlarmId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (KeywordId) REFERENCES Keywords(KeywordId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE (LogAlarmId, KeywordId)
);

CREATE TABLE XRefUserLogAlarmSNSTopic (
    UserLogAlarmSNSTopicId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LogAlarmId INT NOT NULL,
    SNSTopicId INT NOT NULL,
    UserId INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (UserLogAlarmSNSTopicId),
    FOREIGN KEY (LogAlarmId) REFERENCES LogAlarms(LogAlarmId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (SNSTopicId) REFERENCES SNSTopics(SNSTopicId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES Users(UserId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE (LogAlarmId, SNSTopicId, UserId)
);```
````

Comment: You seem to want set(u,a,t) or set(i,u,a,t). Presumably none of the 3 must be single-valued for a value in another so {u,a,t} is a CK & this is 5NF. There's nothing odd about that. Whatever design method reference you are using will lead you to this. Explaining "why" is to rewrite a reference--from scratch?--else from what?--so please explain where & why you are stuck in your method, and if you're not stuck in a method then you haven't done reasonable research. "seems rather messy" is not helpful. Please just give needed code. Re errors please post another question with appropriate code [mre]

Comment: Can a given (a,t) subrow be set by multiple users, or one user? Your question wording isn't clear about that. I thought the former, the 1st answer thought the latter. Only my interpretation is consistent with your code having declared all relevant constraints.

Answer (score 0):

To match your description, your `XRefUserLogAlarmSNSTopic` is not correct.

You do not actually want to link three entities, just two: you want to *relate log alarms to AWS SNS topics* (which are the two values that identify that relationship), and then add a user as an *attribute* to that relation. Although in this case this specific attribute refers to another entity, it is logically not fundamentally different than e.g. a timestamp that stores when that relationsship was created (by that user).

The difference to your current table is the primary key/unique key: your current table allows you to add a relationship between an alarm and a topic several times if different users add them, as only `(alarm, topic, user)` needs to be unique, instead of `(alarm, topic)` being unique, and `user` being an attribute to that relation.

I would also consider if you want an `ON DELETE CASCADE` for the `UserId` column. While cascading for `LogAlarmId` and `SNSTopicId` makes sense, it's not obvious that you need to remove all relations when you delete the user that created them (although it of course depends on your requirements). It may be better to just set them to `null`. So I would propose a table like

```
CREATE TABLE XRefLogAlarmSNSTopic (   -- user not part of table name
    LogAlarmSNSTopicId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    LogAlarmId INT NOT NULL,
    SNSTopicId INT NOT NULL,
    UserId INT NULL,  -- null
    PRIMARY KEY (UserLogAlarmSNSTopicId),
    FOREIGN KEY (LogAlarmId) REFERENCES LogAlarms(LogAlarmId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (SNSTopicId) REFERENCES SNSTopics(SNSTopicId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES Users(UserId) ON DELETE SET NULL,  -- set null
    UNIQUE (LogAlarmId, SNSTopicId)  -- user not part of primary key candidate
)
```

It is obviously also possible that you *want* that 3-way-relationship, e.g. each user creates *their own* alarm-topic-relations, in which case your table would be correct, just your description would not be precise enough.